# USB Connection Not Registering on Phone

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb, usb-debugging, htc

Starting about two weeks ago, I've been having some issues with my HTC Vivid running 4.0.3 regarding the USB port

For charging, once I plug it in it takes about 20 seconds before it registers and shows the charging icon.

My real problem however is that the phone will no longer show up as a drive when I connect to my PC. The computer beeps, but the phone never responds. (After a while it will start to charge, and that's it)

How should I go about trying to solve the problem? Is it an issue with the hardware or Android? Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Instead of editing your question, you should post the solution as an answer as soon as the option is available to you (the delay is 8 hours after posting the question).

Comment: @onik New-user restriction: OP can only do so after 8 hours (and accept after 2 days). **TheFutureIsWild:** Would be nice if you could transfer your solution to an answer then :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per [TheFutureIsWild](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/59374/2):

> Doing a RESTART (not turning off and on) fixed the problem. Also make sure you have a USB data cable, not just a charging one.